# Hibernate automatically appending 1=2 to the generated query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

Hibernate is generating the SQL for the following query :

```
select pcp.id from PersistentContentProfile pcp where pcp.service.id = :service_id and exists(select 1 from Subscription s where s.contentProfile.id = pcp.id and s.status in (:statuses))
```

as native PostgreSQL query :

```
select persistent0_.id as col_0_0_ 
from ems.nlt_content_profile persistent0_ 
where 
1=2 and 
persistent0_.service_id=? and 
(exists (select 1 
        from ems.nlt_subscription subscripti1_ 
        where subscripti1_.content_profile_id=persistent0_.id and 
        (subscripti1_.status in (?,?))))
```

Observed

> '1=2'

getting appended to the query? Why is this getting added? Due to this, no records are retrieved.

Comment: Ravi, can you post your class heirarchy?

Comment: I figured out it was due to a configuration mistake. I was using @ForceDiscriminator and only the abstract class was configured in persistence.xml while configuration for any concrete subsclass was missing.  Still, it would have been helpful if an appropriate error was thrown instead of just appending 1=2 to avoid any results.

Comment: Leaving this here...`hibernate-core-5.1.1.Final-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/sql/InFragment.java:63`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out it was due to a configuration mistake. I was using @ForceDiscriminator and only the abstract class was configured in persistence.xml while configuration for any concrete subsclass was missing.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen for one of two reasons.  It relates to polymorphic entities.  To fix this, you need to make sure that you are passing the base class (not any subclass) to the createCriteria call.  You also need to make sure that any subclasses represented in the database are registered with hibernate.